# Linq query to find non-numeric items in list?

Tags: linq, list, types

Suppose I have the following list:

```
        var strings = new List<string>();
        strings.Add("1");
        strings.Add("12.456");
        strings.Add("Foobar");
        strings.Add("0.56");
        strings.Add("zero");
```

Is there some sort of query I can write in Linq that will return to me only the numeric items, i.e. the 1st, 2nd, and 4th items from the list?

-R.

Comment: Step back and ask yourself why you're dealing with stringly typed data in a single list? I'm merely speculating, but perhaps the answer here is to redefine the problem.

Comment: @Anthony: the data is coming back to me as an array of strings beyond my control, which I'm just doing .ToList() on to try and put into some query to get only the numeric data, and then from there I'll specify the types.

Comment: @Randy, you don't need to call `ToList()` on an array to use it in a query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strings.Where(s => { double ignored; return double.TryParse(s, out ignored); })
```

This will return all the strings that are parseable as `double`s as strings. If you want them as numbers (which makes more sense), you could write an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<double> GetDoubles(this IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
    foreach (var s in strings)
    {
        double result;
        if (double.TryParse(s, out result))
            yield return result;
    }
}
```

Don't forget that `double.TryParse()` uses your current culture, so it will give different results on different computers. If you don't want that, use `double.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result)`.

Comment: D'oh. I knew it'd be something simple. Went brain dead - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    double dummy = 0;
    var strings = new List<string>();
    strings.Add("1");
    strings.Add("12.456");
    strings.Add("Foobar");
    strings.Add("0.56");
    strings.Add("zero");
    var numbers = strings.Where(a=>double.TryParse(a, out dummy));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple predicate to examine each string, like so:

```
var strings = new List<string>();
        strings.Add("1");
        strings.Add("12.456");
        strings.Add("Foobar");
        strings.Add("0.56");
        strings.Add("zero");

var nums = strings.Where( s => s.ToCharArray().All( n => Char.IsNumber( n ) || n == '.' ) );
```

Comment: What about negative numbers? And what about exponential notation (it's not clear whether that should be handled)?

Comment: @svick OP didn't specify either of those constraints. This is a 'quick and dirty' validation using assumptions based on sample data provided in question. Personally, I think "TryParse" has a lot of unnecessary overhead for a simple validation with trivial sample data provided. This answer is not intended for 'mission critical' validation, just an alternative to more complex solutions (left to OP to decide based on his needs).

Comment: I can see the point of “quick and dirty” if it's much shorter than the proper solution, or in similar cases, but I'm not sure that's the case here. As for performance, I really doubt that it's an issue here, so I wouldn't base my decision on that.

Comment: @svick That's why it's left up to the OP to decide what best fits his needs. As I stated previously, this is simply an alternative solution.